# Moment Timezone - Invalid Date

Tags: javascript, momentjs

In the snippet below, parsing `moment.tz('30 3 14:59', 'w d HH:mm', 'America/Los_Angeles');` works fine but changing 14:59 to anything between 15:00 and 23:59 gives an `Invalid date`.

```
var validTime = moment.tz('30 3 14:59', 'w d HH:mm', 'America/Los_Angeles');
console.log(validTime.format()); // 2018-07-25T14:59:00-07:00


var invalidTime = moment.tz('30 3 15:00', 'w d HH:mm', 'America/Los_Angeles');
console.log(invalidTime.format()); // Invalid date
```

https://jsfiddle.net/084e2k91/26/

What's the issue here?

Comment: I'm not getting an `Invalid Date` in your fiddle (I tried 15:59)

Comment: I tried that also. Everything is working for me.

Comment: Interesting, I'll look around. My local timezone is Japan if that makes any difference...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's really interesting because I am also having the same problem, I think this is a bug in the `moment.js` which is not converting the date from other time zones. But when you try with `do` then everything seems fine. So my suggestion would be let use `do` for time being while time we raise this issue in GitHub.

And `do` is the same as `d` can be checked here in the [docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/). It means both return same day but one as a `number` other as a `string`.

With more experiment I found in IST after 18:30 the problem is starting. But the cause is really not understandable to me. But maybe cause is the addition of timezone value to the real-time which is causing the error. Mean if I am in IST then `00:00 - 5:30` is the same time from when the error occurs.

So updated code should be like following:

```js
var myTime1 = moment.tz('30 3 14:59', 'w d HH:mm', 'America/Los_Angeles');
console.log(myTime1.format());

var myTime = moment.tz('30 3rd 14:59', 'w do HH:mm', 'America/Los_Angeles');
console.log(myTime.format());





//In IST the problem is starting from 18:30
var myTime1 = moment.tz('30 3 19:30', 'w d HH:mm', 'America/Los_Angeles');
console.log(myTime1.format());


var myTime1 = moment.tz('30 3rd 19:30', 'w do HH:mm', 'America/Los_Angeles');
console.log(myTime1.format());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.21/moment-timezone-with-data-2012-2022.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, changing it to `do` worked for me. If it helps, I noticed that when I change my computer's local timezone to GMT+8:00 or earlier it works. But once I change it to GMT+8:30 or later, I get the issue mentioned in the post.

Comment: @matt-johnson Can you please have a look on this?

Comment: Looks like I spoke too soon. Using `do` gives me `2018-07-22T15:00:00-07:00` instead of `2018-07-25T15:00:00-07:00`. Also tried changing the `3` to `3rd`.

Comment: Yes seems like the problem is not getting solved by that. Will let you know after an hour let me do some more research.

Comment: @journalismIsDead The problem was occurring due to the old version of moment the current version doesn't have this problem. I have updated the my answer please verify.